# CSV file keeps changing numbers on generated CSV file using php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, type-conversion

i am working in mysql table to generate CSV file conversion using php.

Credit card numbers are shown in mysql database like this **44445959636345**. When i  converting mysql table to csv file it doesn't show proper credit card number shown just like this **4.4446E+13**

My sql query is  `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);`

CSV files changes all the card numbers! For example if your card

**44445959636345**

Instead of showing up as shown above... CSV changes it and makes it show up as:

**4.4446E+13**

How can i solve this issue please guide me.

Comment: How do you view the csv file, could also be a problem of the editor (ie excel)

Comment: your storing cc numbers in your db?

Comment: credit card number contain 16 number of characters but excel cell accept only 15 characters only so only the format change.  in excel, if i am click the 4.4446E+13 number it shows 44445959636345 full details but i need to show 44445959636345 directly.

Comment: have you tried to put number in csv in formula like `=44445959636345`?

Comment: A credit card number is too long for a 32-bit intger value in MS Excel or in PHP, so it needs to be treated as a string.... and (memo to self) never trust somebody that stores plaintext cc number s in an Excel file, especially if it's for download

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the csv file in excel you can put a single quote in front of the number that way it will be displayed as text.
WARNING this means that you need to remove that quote when importing a csv file like this into your DB. This can be done with php or sql substring functions.
so instead of 44445959636345 output '44445959636345 to your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: the function refers to the credit number as an integer. What you have to do is to make it refer to it as a text.